# Can const data members have different values between translation units?

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

I'm wondering if it is permitted to declare the same class multiple times using different *values* for a const member, or if this would be an ODR violation? Consider this example with two independent translation units that are going to be linked into some `libx` library:

```
// x.h
#pragma once

class X {
  const int x = VALUE;
};
```

```
// x1.cpp
#define VALUE 1
#include "x.h"

int fn1() {
  X x;
  return x.x;
}
```

```
// x2.cpp
#define VALUE 2
#include "x.h"

int fn2() {
  X x;
  return x.x;
}
```

Also, in case this is not legal, does it make a difference whether `x` is declared `const` or not?

Comment: You do have ODR violation.

Comment: See [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule). Each definition of your class has to be exactly identical.

Comment: Unrelated to `const` BTW.

Comment: `#pragma once` is non-standard. Now there are multiple compilers by now that support it, but when you start writing code like this (with ODR violations) the use of `#pragma once` with its non-standard semantics might make bughunting harder.

Comment: Note the ODR "header" flavor allowing one definition per TU requires that all definitions have the same tokens AND all names used have the same meaning. Answers point out that this code violates the "same tokens" part, but switching from the `#define` to things like `static constexpr int VALUE = 1;` would violate the "same meaning" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, different objects can have different `const` data members. The issue that the comments are focussing on is in the way that the data member gets initialized, which doesn't really address the issue.

```
struct s {
    const int x;
    s(int xx) : x(xx) {}
};

s s1(1);
s s2(2);
```

What you can't do is define the same name in multiple translation units with a different definition:

```
// a1.cpp
s s1(1);

// a2.cpp
s s1(2);
```

that's a violation of the one definition rule. But it has nothing to do with the `const` data member; the same problem would occur if `s::x` was not `const`. And you'd have an ODR violation in your original example if `x` was plain `int`, not `const`.

Answer (score 1):

From [One Definition Rule's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule):

> There can be more than one definition in a program of each of the following: **class type**, enumeration type, inline function, inline variable (since C++17), templated entity (template or member of template, but not full template specialization), **as long as** all of the following is true:
>
> - each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens (typically, appears in the same header file)

So you have ODR violation in your program. Also this is **independent** of whether the data member is `const` or not.

Answer (score 0):

No.

> Each such definition shall consist of the same sequence of tokens

You can can find the legalese in §6.3 [basic.def.odr]